# How to get access to variables from another scene Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to create upgrades for my player.
I have the player stats in game.js (for example `let player_speed = 300`).

I've created another scene that contains the UI of the upgrades like so:

upgradeScene.js

```
import IncreaseSpeed from './Upgrades/increase_speed.js';
import IncreaseDamage from './Upgrades/increase_damage.js';
import IncreaseFireRate from './Upgrades/increase_firerate.js';
export default class Upgrade extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super('upgradeScene');
    }

    preload() {

        this.load.image('bg', 'Assets/UI/bg.png');

    }

    create() {

        const screenCenterX = this.cameras.main.worldView.x + this.cameras.main.width / 2;
        const screenCenterY = this.cameras.main.worldView.y + this.cameras.main.height / 2;

        bg = this.add.image(screenCenterX, screenCenterY, 'bg').setAlpha(0.5);

        title = this.add.text(screenCenterX, screenCenterY - 300, 'UPGRADES', {
            fontFamily: 'dogicaPixel',
            fontSize: '40px',
            align: 'center'
        }).setOrigin(0.5);

        p = this.add.text(screenCenterX, screenCenterY - 260, 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', {
            fontFamily: 'dogicaPixel',
            fontSize: '15px',
            align: 'center'
        }).setOrigin(0.5);
        
        this.scene.add(this, IncreaseSpeed, true);
        this.scene.add(this, IncreaseDamage, true);
        this.scene.add(this, IncreaseFireRate, true);
```

Increase_speed.js

```
export default class IncreaseSpeed extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super('increase_speed');
    }

    preload() {
        this.load.image('cardbg', './Assets/UI/cardbg.png');
    }

    create() {

        const screenCenterX = this.cameras.main.worldView.x + this.cameras.main.width / 2;
        const screenCenterY = this.cameras.main.worldView.y + this.cameras.main.height / 2;

        rectC = this.add.image(0, 0, 'cardbg');

        increase_speed_title = this.add.text(0, -100, 'Increase\nSpeed', {
            fontFamily: 'dogicaPixel',
            fontSize: '20px',
            align: 'center'
        }).setOrigin(0.5);

        increase_speed_description = this.add.text(0, 0, 'Lorem ipsum\ndolor sit amet', {
            fontFamily: 'dogicaPixel',
            fontSize: '15px',
            align: 'center'
        }).setOrigin(0.5);

        increase_speed_btn = this.add.text(0, 120, 'UPGRADE', {
            fontFamily: 'dogicaPixel',
            fontSize: '20px',
            align: 'center'
        }).setOrigin(0.5).setInteractive();

        cardC = this.add.container(screenCenterX, screenCenterY, [rectC, increase_speed_title, increase_speed_description, increase_speed_btn]);

        // increase_speed_btn.on('pointerdown', () => {
        //     console.log('test');
        // });
    }

    update() {
        increase_speed_btn.on('pointerover', function (pointer) {
            increase_speed_btn.setScale(1.5);
        })

        increase_speed_btn.on('pointerout', function (pointer) {
            increase_speed_btn.setScale(1);
        })
    }
}
```

I would like to increase the player_speed when you click on the button in order to set the upgrade.

I'm still learning, I've done research about that but I'm confused cause I haven't find a way to 'communicate' between scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can communicate between scene with the Phaser EventEmitters ([link to Documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Events.EventEmitter.html)). You just have to `emit` and listen(`on`) on the same Emitter.
In this case, after adding the scene, you get the correct Emitter, with `this.scene.get(...).events`.

**Here a small working demo:**
*(Just click the red "Click me" text)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

class Scene2 extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor(){
      super('scene2');
  }
  
  create() {
    this.add.text(10, 40, 'SCEEN-SPEED', {color: '#ff0000'}).setOrigin(0);
    
    let button = this.add.text(10, 70, 'CLICK ME => 100 SPEED', {color: '#ff0000', fontStyle: 'bold'})
      .setOrigin(0)
      .setInteractive()
      .on('pointerdown', () => this.events.emit('speed-increase', 100));
  }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
      key: 'scene1',
      create,
      update
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {
    this.playerSpeed = 0;
    this.playerSpeedText = this.add.text(10, 10, '', { color: '#ffffff'}).setOrigin(0);
    
    this.scene.add(this, Scene2, true);
    this.scene.get('scene2').events.on('speed-increase', speed => this.playerSpeed = speed);
}

function update(){
  this.playerSpeedText.setText(`Player Speed: ${this.playerSpeed}`);
  if(this.playerSpeed > 99){
    this.playerSpeedText.setColor('#00ff00');
  }
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

**Update:**
If I understand this correct you have:

- "gameScene" that adds a "upgradeScene".
- and the "upgradeScene" adds several specific Scenes like "increaseSpeedScene" and so on

If this is the case, this makes the things abit more complex, but still possible.

> you won't need to import anything else *(I think)*, just add the following code in the specific files.

In the **"gameScene"**, in the `create` function (or after the adding of the UpgradeScene), add:

```
 this.scene.get('Upgrade-Scene-Key')
     .events.on('upgrade-action', speed => this.playerSpeed = speed);
```

In the **"UpdatedScene"** in the `create` function (or after the adding the specific Scenes) add:

```
 // this you could do for all upgrade options
 this.scene.get('IncreaseSpeed-Scene-key')
     .events.on('upgrade-speed', speed => this.events
    .emit('upgrade-action', speed));
```

And in the **"IncreaseSpeedScene"**, just add the `emit` function call to the button event callback:

```
// just be sure that the context of this = the current scene
this.events.emit('upgrade-speed', 100)
```

With other words, you have now one extra event emitter(in the UpgradeScene), that just passes the Event and the Data to the gameScene.

I hope this clears things up abit.

> btw.: the names of the event 'upgrade-action', 'upgrade-speed', ... can be choose more or less freely, they just have to match between emiter (`emit` function) and listener (`on` function)

Comment: Thank you so much for the example. But I'm confused cause I have the player script in the game.js and in the UpgradeScene.js I have imported the classes which are the upgrades (Increase-speed.js ...)

So I was wondering what do I have to  import and where in other to change the  player speed after I click the button

Comment: @Adele I updated the answer, I hopes this helps you clear up your confusion.

Comment: Yeah i mean i don't add the UpgradeScene, I just pause the game and play that scene.
Cause you have to collect objects in order to fill a bar and when the bar is full you level up, so in the level up func I pause the game and play the upgradeScene.

Comment: but I've tried and I got this error: ```this.scene.emit is not a function``` it's referring to this line: ```this.scene.get('increase_speed_keyScene').events.on('upgrade-speed', speed => this.scene.emit('upgrade-action', speed)); ```

Comment: @Adele sorry, I wrote it wrong in second code snippet, it has to be `this.events.emit` not `this.scene.emit`. I fixed this mistake in the answer. I you update your code it should work now.